# Transformar string em número

Tags: javascript, string, float

Estou com um problema que para muitos são simples, estou com um código que pega o valor de um `input` do tipo `hidden` e quando pego esse valor, eu add +1, ou seja, se o valor for 3 ele add +1 e tem que ficar 4:

```
var total = $("#total").attr('value') + 1;
```

Ele teria que ficar 4 e alterar o `value` do input para 4:

```
$("#total").val(total);
```

só que ele me retorna **Valor Atual + 1** ou seja, **31**, **41** como se fosse string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) para transformar a string em um número inteiro ou [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), caso o valor seja um número com casas decimais.

**parseInt**:

```
var total = parseInt($("#total").attr('value')) + 1;
```

**parseFloat**:

```
var total = parseFloat($("#total").attr('value')) + 1;
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu!!

Answer (score 4):

Apesar de você estar usando jQuery para pegar o atributo, isso é comportamento padrão da linguagem JavaScript. Ao usar o operador de soma entre um número e uma string, o número é convertido para string.

Minha maneira preferida de resolver é usar o [operador unário `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) na frente da string, assim:

```
var total = +$("#total").attr('value') + 1;
```

Comment: Isso me parece gambiarra, igual utilizar `"" + 1` para converter int para string.

Comment: É diferente, é um outro operador. Não é soma, é o `+` unário que serve justamente para forçar a conversão (ver o link na resposta).

Comment: Legal, não sabia que dava pra fazer assim também. +1

Comment: @AndréRibeiro +1 ou `+"1"`? ;)

Comment: @bfavaretto Boa :D